# How to write makefile for Python(turn into a executable file)?

Tags: python

I need to write a makefile to turn my python codes into executable file. For example, I have main.py , utility.py. I need an executable file name "run" such that ./run can be executed. I tried "python main.py run" in the Makefile but it says that missing separator ?

Comment: I'm afraid a Makefile isn't enough to convert Python scripts into executables. You'll need something like py2exe or Cython

Comment: When you say executable ? You just mean to make `main.py` run, right ? Put the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line of your `main.py` and `chmod 744 main.py` and then do `./main.py`. Also i am assuming you are calling your `main` function in the `main.py` file somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I'm missing something, but why wouldn't a **.py** script be executable?

As long as the Python interpreter is installed in the system, you can run .py files from shell. I don't see the need for you *"run"* script.

In any case, you could create a script with the command you want to execute, in this case:

```
python main.py
```

or

```
python main.py && python utility.py
```

to run more than one python script at once.

(Always paying attention to the real name of the python interpreter present in your system. It could be python37, python27...)

Maybe there is something about your particular problem that I'm not getting right...

I'm happy to keep discussing

Comment: Actually that works and it is also the way that I test my program. However, my instructor asks us to submit a "makefile" thing along with those ".py" file which can make them executable. Then I do not know how to do that.